# Iframe content loading before css with Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, iframe

I've a problem with an iFrame, which I load content dynamically and compile HTML with JavaScript. All works fine with all browsers, but with Firefox I have a small lag between HTML loading and CSS loading.
It display the iFrame content at first (raw HTML), and a few seconds later CSS is displaying.

Is it a Firefox issue, or a specific operation of the browser ?
And I want to know if there is some solutions to resolve this ?

I've found this during my researches, and I think this is nearly the same problem : 
http://www.phpied.com/when-is-a-stylesheet-really-loaded/
and this : https://support.mozilla.org/fr/questions/970521

Answer (score 0):

Could be a solution if you use fade after document ready.
If you have a browser detection you can add class to body like .ff for firefox.

```
#main-content { display: none; }


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#main-content').fadeIn();
});
```

or use browser detection jquery
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/

```
 if ( $.browser.webkit ) {
    alert( "This is WebKit!" );
  }
```

Comment: But the iFrame is loaded and displayed on demand, so it will not really resolve my problem, but only hide it...